# Divergence of inverse square field (2D vs. 3D)

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator

Let $\displaystyle\mathbf{v}=\frac{\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{r^2}$.

Compute its divergence.

**My attempt:**

I found that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$ in the 3D case, in accordance with Gauss' law, but $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}\ne 0$ in the 2D case. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. Try to calculate the electric field due to an infinitely long straight wire. You will see that the field is proportional to $1/r$, and not $1/r^2$ like in 3D. So in 2D is just "inverse distance" not "inverse squared distance".

Comment: what about r=0 ? something as a Dirac delta?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui It is indeed. But the question was (I think) about the rest of the space. Once you understand that the $\mathbf v$ would have to be $1/r$ type everywhere to get the 2D divergence to be $0$ (except at $r=0$), you can talk about the integral.